# Convert Spring Mongo Update to JSON String

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I have an instance of an `Update` object and I would like to convert it to its String JSON representation so I can use it later.

I created the update object like this:

```
Update update = new Update();
update.set("field", new SomeClass());
update.unset("otherField");
// etc
```

My initial attempt was:

```
update.getUpdateObject().toString();
```

This approach worked for most cases but it failed occasionally because it could not serialize an instance of `SomeClass`. This was the stacktrace:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: json can't serialize type : class com.example.SomeClass
at com.mongodb.util.JSON.serialize(JSON.java:261)
    at com.mongodb.util.JSON.serialize(JSON.java:115)
    at com.mongodb.util.JSON.serialize(JSON.java:161)
    at com.mongodb.util.JSON.serialize(JSON.java:141)
    at com.mongodb.util.JSON.serialize(JSON.java:58)
    at com.mongodb.BasicDBObject.toString(BasicDBObject.java:84)
```

I have available an instance of `MongoTemplate` and `MongoConverter` but I am unsure about how to use these classes to do this task.

The question is:

What's the correct way to get the JSON representation of an Update object?

I'm using spring-data-mongodb version 1.1.0.M1.

Comment: Just to verify, is `SomeClass` `Serializable`?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by using,

```
Update update = new Update();

JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(new SomeClass());

update.set("field",JSON.parse(jsonObject.toString()));
update.unset("otherField");

System.out.println(update.getUpdateObject().toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

I've met the same problem, and solved by turning `SomeClass` into `DBObject`:

```
DBObject dbObject = new BasicDBObject();
dbObject.put("fieldA", "a"); // set all fields of SomeClass
...

update.set("field", dbObject);
```